# Why some .gif icons not playing on android project xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I want to display some .gif icons on android project.. but many icons not moving.. I don't know why.. ?

I have a `<Image/>` with propertie: `IsAnimationPlaying="True"` and this work only for three gifs and other gifs not moved...

```
                    <Image Source="rain.gif"
                           IsAnimationPlaying="True"
                           WidthRequest="40"
                           HeightRequest="40"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
```

In drawable folder I set all gifs to AndroidResource property but this not work..

Аnd after all, the icon is not the one I placed in drawable folder.

I set rain.gif who is not this one from the screenshot.

[image: This is not the icon who I set]

This is real icon `rain.gif`:
[image: rain.gif]

So the first three .gif icons is moved and worked (thermometers), other .gif icons not worked and rain.gif is different I don't know why ?

Could it be that the problem is that I have the same name with different extensions in `drawable` folder, like: `rain.jpg` `rain.png`...

I try many times to clear the project and build again and again but not worked for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becasue Android doesn't have built-in support for loading gif into `ImageViews`.
You could display gif with some commonly used third-party controls.

Like [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading)

```
<ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage Source="rain.gif" WidthRequest="40"
                       HeightRequest="40"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: When I use this code I receive this error: The type 'ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: @PizhevRacing You could install the FFImageLoading nuget package first !